# Display a 3D image with vtk python

Tags: python, vtk

I want to Display a 3D image with the vtk module python. The image was saved in .vti format. I wrote the following simple code but it does not work correctly. How i can fix that?

```
import vtk

file_name = 'Vug.vti'

# Read the source file.
reader = vtk.vtkNrrdReader()
reader.SetFileName(file_name)
reader.Update()  

# Map the image through the lookup table
color = vtk.vtkImageMapToColors()
#color.SetLookupTable(table)
color.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

# Display the image
actor = vtk.vtkImageActor()
actor.GetMapper().SetInputConnection(color.GetOutputPort())

renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(actor)

window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
window.AddRenderer(renderer)

# Set up the interaction
interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
window.SetInteractor(interactor)
window.Render()

# Start interaction
interactor.Start()
```

Comment: Could you explain what is wrong with the code?

Comment: It shows the image in 2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vtkImageActor displays an image as a 2d object.  If you want to render a 3d volume, you need to use a vtkVolume object.

This example shows how to volume render in VTK:
https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Examples/VolumeRendering/Python/SimpleRayCast.py

Answer (score 0):

With [vtkplotter](https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter) this is simply:

```py
from vtkplotter import load, datadir, show
vol = load(datadir + 'vase.vti') # returns vtkVolume
# set color and trasparency transfer functions along the scalar range
vol.color(["green", "pink", "blue"]).alpha([0, 0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.9])
show(vol)
```